# How to change the default image of facebook button in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

**Please Help**

This is what happening now...custom image what i need is overlapping with the log-in text of default facebook button ,but i don't want default log-in text which is in background.it is also automatically logging-in.. once if i log in in the app

Comment: Basically I don't understand what are you trying to ask...so what is your question...please ask with some detail

Comment: am not able to put screenshot images.....now i have explained in detail about what is happening

Comment: am new to this ...can u please share any links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**May be it works for you.**

```
FBLoginView *fbLoginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]];


    fbLoginView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 271, 37);
     for (id obj in fbLoginView.subviews)
        {
            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
                UIButton * loginButton =  obj;
                UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImg.png"];
                [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
                [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
                [loginButton sizeToFit];
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom facebook button, its very bad practice to iterate through subviews in order to attempt to force something that wasn't intended, also, it's not hard to just make your own button and implement the graph API with the methods below, these work, they pull data, they allow you customize everything and they leave your with a pretty damn good method for the future that can be used and customized in any app:

```
UIButton *_facebookButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[[_facebookButton layer] setCornerRadius:2.5];
[_facebookButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:FALSE];
[_facebookButton setTitle:@"Sign in with Facebook" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[_facebookButton titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
[_facebookButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_facebookButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor facebookBlue]];
[_facebookButton setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[_facebookButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -135, 0, -2)];
[_facebookButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facebookIconBlue"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[_facebookButton layer] setMasksToBounds:TRUE];
[_facebookButton addTarget:self action:@selector(facebookButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addSubview:_facebookButton];
```

Method to handle logging in:

```
-(void)facebookButtonPressed {
    if(![FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error){
             if (error)  {
                 //do work
             }
             else if (result.isCancelled) {
                 // do work
             }
             else
             {
                 if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
                     [self loadUserData];
                 }
             }
         }];
    }
    else {
        [self loadUserData];
    }
}
```

the method above then attaches itself to this method to pull data form the Facebook token:

```
- (void)loadUserData {
    if([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
         FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name"}];
        [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;
                 NSString *facebookID = userData[@"id"];
                 NSString *link = userData[@"link"];
                 NSString *locale = userData[@"locale"];
                 NSString *timezone = userData[@"timezone"];
                 NSString *last_name = userData[@"last_name"];
                 NSString *email = userData[@"email"];
                 NSString *gender = userData[@"gender"];
                 NSString *first_name = userData[@"first_name"];

                 //**** THIS IS WHERE YOU PUSH YOUR VIEW CONTROLLER, THE USER IS NOW LOGGED IN AND YOU HAVE THE DATA YOU NEED TO RECORD ON YOUR SERVER BACKEND***
             }
             else if (error) {

             }
         }];
    }
    else if (![FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    }
}
```

Please make sure to note the portion above that indicates where you can consider the user "authenticated". Iterating through subviews to get to the view that you can change is "OKAY", but it's not good practice at all. It's better to use your own custom button if don't like the way the Facebook login button looks. I hope this helps you.

Comment: you pass parameter as nil, so facebbok sdk 4.x not support that you request parameter then you get otherwise not get data.

Comment: this works for me right now, it's working just as it should, I'm not sure I understand what you are saying

Comment: i know but just knowledge for you `FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]; ` here not pass nil value in Facebook sdk version 4.0 or higher.

Comment: Ahh yeah, that's right, I forgot to put in the parameters, you are correct, I have them declared somewhere else and this was from a past build, my bad, thank you

Comment: A custom facebook button IS GOOD practice, the iteration of subviews on the facebook "log in" button that facebook allos you to use is BAD PRACTICE

Comment: but that button is not as customizable as making your own button and then attaching methods to the button, you can't do the customization as you see in my answer above, you can't mess around with the insets you can't adjust the picture according to design dimensions without iterating subviews. Facebook exposes just a few options to customize this button.